# Node Fetch url, how to strip off hostname port

Tags: node.js, reactjs, fetch

I'm using node-fetch along with react.js. As mentioned in the document, I can cache an image buffer in this way.

```
var fileType = require('file-type');
fetch('https://assets-cdn.github.com/images/modules/logos_page/Octocat.png')
.then(function(res) {
    return res.buffer();
}).then(function(buffer) {
    fileType(buffer);
});
```

But since my react.js running on localhost:3000, the fetch request will automatically append :3000 in the url. In this case, https://assets-cdn.github.com**:3000**/images/modules/logos_page/Octocat.png.

But this URL is not valid, how can I remove the port?

Comment: If you pass a fully qualified URL, `fetch()` will not add a port.

Answer (score 1):

The port shouldn't be added when you have a full URL with `https://host/path`.

But if it doesn't work for you for some reason and you want to have a certain port in the URL then you can always add it explicitly:

- https://assets-cdn.github.com:443/images/modules/logos_page/Octocat.png

443 is the default port for the HTTPS protocol and this URL works (but the browser will hide the port number when you click it, just like it hides the port 80 for HTTP).

Comment: After explictly adding the port, there's another error `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.`

Comment: @Klyment Where do you get this error? In Node or in React?

Comment: I figure out why. It's webpack problem, Adding a header to the webpack.config.js will solve the issue. `headers: { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "http://localhost:3000", "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true" }`